How to convert a column of Japanese words in a column of Hiragana words in Excel
I have a large column of Japanese words (some are entirely in hiragana, katakana or kanji, some are a mix of kanji and hiragana, and some are a mix of kanji and katakana), and I would like to convert that column of words into another column with exactly those same words but all of them written entirely in hiragana.
So for example, if in that first column there are words like this:
ゆっくり
ファッション
家族
落ち着く
アア溶岩
I would like to convert that into:
ゆっくり
ふぁっしょん
かぞく
おちつく
ああようがん
Looking for some information about it on Google, I've read that something can be done with VBA programming inside Excel, but I have no idea of programming and I couldn't understand barely anything.

EDIT: I don't know if this would be possible, but another option would be that for the first word of the column I would like to convert, Excel goes to this website:
https://www.jcinfo.net/ja/tools/kana
inserts that word in the textbox, clicks the option below "カタカナを含める" to activate it, clicks the blue botton "ふりがな変換", and from the three result boxes that appear under the blue botton, grabs the result from the third box (the last one) and pastes it in a certain cell in my Excel document. And then, to repeat this with the rest of the words.

Could you please help me to get this function done in Excel whatever method is used?
Thank you very much for all the help you can offer me.
EDIT 2 (4/9/2024): This topic is solved in
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-convert-a-column-of-japanese-words-in-a-column-of-hiragana-words-in-excel.1263732/
